# Retonar sugestões de endereços o número com google places Api

Tags: javascript, react

Estou usando a api do Google para a busca de endereços.
A api funciona corretamento, porém eu preciso que a api me retorne os dados já com o número do local.

Atualmente a api me retorna algo como:
Av. Paulista - Bela Vista, São Paulo - SP, Brasil

Eu gostaria que quando o usuário digitasse "Avenida Paulista" apenas fossem exibidos os resultados seguido do número, como por exemplo faz o Uber e Rappi.

Segue o trecho do meu código em que eu faço a busca:

```
     const options = {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: ['br']
        }
    }; 

    // Initialize Google Autocomplete
    /*global google*/ // To disable any eslint 'google not defined' errors
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'),
      options
    );

    // Fire Event when a suggested name is selected
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.handlePlaceSelect);
```

Answer (score 0):

O que o Uber faz é usar o [Place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details).

Você precisa passar o `placeid` que você obtêm fazendo uma [busca do local](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

No resultado desse endpoint vem o numero da rua.